# 2 elements in the same row if only the width of one element is known

Tags: android, android-layout

In android I have 1 seekbar which width is not known. I have also a button which width is 100dp.
I wanna to place both the seekbar and the button on the same line. The seekbar first. The seekbar should fill all the remaining place. Parent - 100dp. I'm trying to achieve this and tried in any way but I can't achieve this..any suggestion ?

Comment: set a fixed size for your button and a layout_weight="1" on the seekbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding both the elements under  a LinearLayout and put weights on it.
Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put both elements in RelativeLayout.

- Set layout width to fill parent
- Give the button width of 100dp
- Set button's **layout_alignParentRight** property to **True**
- Set the SeekBar widh to fill parent
- Set the SeekBar to be left of the button

```xml
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <SeekBar 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```